# How does it works? Sequence of computing variable into printf

Tags: c

stumbled upon such a puzzle:

What will be shown on the screen?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int x = 10;
    printf("x = %d, y = %d", x--, x++);
}
```

Curiously enough, but shown at the screen this: x = 11, y = 10;
But how??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior)

Comment: Also: [Parameter evaluation order before a function calling in C](//stackoverflow.com/a/376333)

Answer (score 1):

Argument Evaluation Order is undefined in both C and C++. It's important to avoid any code that passes expressions dependent on each other that has to be evaluated before the function is called. It's a strict no.

```
int f1() { printf("F1") ; return 1;}
int f2() { printf("F2" ) ; return 1;}
printf("%d%d", f1(), f2()) ;
```

You can check out by adding several functions that contain a print statement and pass it to a function to observe this in action.  You don't know what's coming, the C standard doesn't specify it, it depends on what compiler you use and how it optimizes your code.